# Как разместить картинки таким методом? Грид, Флекс-бокс?

Tags: html, flexbox, css-grid

Таким образом должны быть размещены таким образом, гридами или флекс-боксами, ну или другим более удобным методом

[image: Описание]

Comment: `width: 285px; height: 208px;` да и всё, никаких гридов и флексбоксов

Comment: Беда в том, что по умолчанию картинки не будут становится в ряды. Можно включить обтекание элементов текстом и другими элементами. Тогда элементы будут располагаться типа сеткой, но число столбцов будет зависеть от размеров окна и ширины элементов.

Comment: Можно использовать float: left, можно использовать display: table. Можно и flex-box использовать, если нужно сделать это резиновим. Ты скажи что тебе конкретно надо, а то хрен что поймёшь

Answer (score 2):

**Очень простой вариант на CSS**

```css
.gallery {
  font-size: 0;
}

.gallery > img {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=2">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=3">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=4">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=5">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=6">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=7">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=8">
</div>
```

---

**Вариант на display: table**

```css
.gallery {
  display: table;
}

.gallery > img {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=2">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=3">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=4">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=5">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=6">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=7">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=8">
</div>
```

---

**Вариант на Grid**

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
}

.gallery > img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=2">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=3">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=4">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=5">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=6">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=7">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=8">
</div>
```

---

**Вариант на Flexbox**

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gallery > img {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=2">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=3">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=4">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=5">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=6">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/07f/fff?text=7">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff?text=8">
</div>
```